# Время сессии Laravel

Tags: laravel

Все время выходит из приложения Laravel, как установить время сессии на неделю ?

Comment: А разве сейчас нет документации? Есть же `config\session.php[lifetime]` или тот же `env('SESSION_LIFETIME')`

Comment: 'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 100), увеличил все равно выходит через 5 минут

Comment: Что у вас в php.ini? `session.gc_maxlifetime`

Comment: session.gc_maxlifetime = 0